# HTML Validator for websites

Tags: html, validation

I have [website templates](http://www.our-templates.com) and want to validate its HTML. I've heard that there is a w5 or something like that, I don't remember the validator to check HTML errors. So can anyone post me a  link of that?

Comment: It's [W3](http://www.w3.org/), not W5: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%20Validator%20for%20websites

Comment: C'mom Summer of love! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love

Comment: Right, but doesn't that encourage a buildup of totally pointless questions?

Comment: True! But to people like us it is stupid, but to someone else it is like trying to understand a UFO. We go pft at HTML where others would go eh? and the fact they took the time to sign up just to ask the question made me want to provide an answer.

Comment: I understand. And I'm not criticizing the OP for not knowing, that would be just plain mean! What I don't understand is why *anyone* would take the 5-10 **minutes** to do that when you could just google for "html validator" and have the result in *seconds*.

Comment: Who knows... but then again we could question why were having this conversation when the answer has been given... who knows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org/ This is the standard.

> This checks the markup validity of Web documents in HTML, XHTML, SMIL,
>   MathML, etc.

For things like CSS validity you should take a look at: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: @JonathonReinhart At one point we've all been there, and guessing from the guess at 'W5', I reckon the OP's technology background is very 'brief'... which also means the tool will not be that useful for them but we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The website you are looking for is [W3 Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) (http://validator.w3.org/). The *W3* stands for *World Wide Web*.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you expect validation to be. The W3C Markup Validation Service  http://validator.w3.org/ is the usual answer, but it answers a question different from what people usually mean when they ask for validation.

It is originally based on the SGML concept of validation, which is a purely formal process and does *not* check for correctness in general, only syntax rules specified in a formalized way. In addition to detecting actual markup errors, it issues messages about violations of formal syntax that do no harm in any browser (e.g. `title=Hello!` without quotation marks) and accepts constructs that do not work in any browser (say `<em/Hello`). More info: [“HTML validation” is a good tool, but just a tool](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/validation.html).

The W3C Markup Validation Service isn’t really a pure SGML validator (or a pure XML validator) but has some checks and warnings beyond that. There’s a more pure SGML validator: [WDG HTML Validator](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/).

When processing a document declared as HTML5, using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the W3C Markup Validation Service changes it nature: it becomes an ad hoc checker for specifically HTML5, behaving rather differently from an SGML validator. It is described as experimental, and it does not necessarily correspond to the most recent version or HTML5 (or of “HTML Living Standard”). Technically it is based on [Validator.nu Living Validator](http://validator.nu/).

With very small exceptions, these services do not check for the correctness of embedded or linked CSS and JavaScript at all, or links, semantic correctness, usability, accessibility, etc. So a “valid” page may look complete mess and fail to work at all.

There is also software marketed as “HTML validator” (as you can find out by googling), typically performing a large set of heuristic checks, partly based on HTML specifications, partly on other specs, and partly by software vendor’s own ideas of what is correct.